# Pivoting duplicate columns into rows

Tags: python, pandas

This is the input file I have from reading a csv file:

```
Sample Info     D3S1358 1       D3S1358 2       TH01 1      TH01 2      D21S11 1        D21S11 2        D21S11 3
TEST_646            17          17                  9       9.3         28                  28          nan
TEST_647            18          18                  7       7           29                  30          30.2
TEST_648            16          16                  9       9           31.2                31.2        nan
```

I would like to convert it into a form like this:

```
Sample_name  Marker     mrk     value
TEST_646     D3S1358     1      17
TEST_646     D3S1358     2      17
TEST_646     TH01        1      9
TEST_646     TH01        2      9.3
TEST_646     D21S11      1      28.0
TEST_646     D21S11      2      28.0
TEST_646     D21S11      3      nan
```

PS. here are the values in comma-separated form for your convenience:

```
Sample Info, D3S1358 1, D3S1358 2, TH01 1, TH01 2, D21S11 1, D21S11 2, D21S11 3
TEST_646, 17, 17, 9, 9.3, 28, 28, nan
TEST_647, 18, 18, 7, 7, 29, 30, 30.2
TEST_648, 16, 16, 9, 9, 31.2, 31.2, nan
```

My solution so far was:

```
samples = xls.parse(sheet).set_index('Sample Info')
cols = list(set(filter(None, [i[:-2] if i!="Sample Info" else None for i in samples.columns])))
sample_df_d= {'1' : pd.Series( len(cols)*[''], index=cols), '2' : pd.Series( len(cols)*[''], index=cols), '3' : pd.Series( len(cols)*[''], index=cols)}
sample_df_ = pd.DataFrame(sample_df_d)
sample_ser = sample_df_.stack()
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_ser, columns=['value'])
#print sample_df

for i,j in samples.iterrows():
    for i2,j2 in j.iteritems():
            print j[0], i2[:-2], "\t", i2[-2:],"\t", j2
```

which would generate something like this:

```
17 D3S1358   1  17
17 D3S1358   2  17
17 TH01      1  9
17 TH01      2  9.3
17 D21S11    1  28.0
```

Comment: Where is the problem? What did you try?

Comment: Oh, I tried many things, for example putting some series instead of each of those one, but without MultiIndex solution of Andy none worked for me. Sorry for putting problem without my rough solution. Updated the question with my "bad" solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way with stacking, first clean up the columns to a [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex):

```
In [11]: df_1 = df0.set_index('Sample Info')

In [12]: df_1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df_1.columns.map(str.split)),
                                                  names=['Marker', 'mrk'])

In [13]: df_1
Out[13]:
Marker       D3S1358      TH01       D21S11
mrk                1   2     1    2       1     2     3
Sample Info
TEST_646          17  17     9  9.3    28.0  28.0   NaN
TEST_647          18  18     7  7.0    29.0  30.0  30.2
TEST_648          16  16     9  9.0    31.2  31.2   NaN
```

Then you can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (first by `'Marker'` then by `'mrk'`):

```
In [14]: df_2 = df_1.stack(level=['Marker', 'mrk'])

In [15]: df_2
Sample Info  Marker   mrk
TEST_646     D21S11   1      28.0
                      2      28.0
             D3S1358  1      17.0
                      2      17.0
             TH01     1       9.0
                      2       9.3
TEST_647     D21S11   1      29.0
                      2      30.0
                      3      30.2
             D3S1358  1      18.0
                      2      18.0
             TH01     1       7.0
                      2       7.0
TEST_648     D21S11   1      31.2
                      2      31.2
             D3S1358  1      16.0
                      2      16.0
             TH01     1       9.0
                      2       9.0
dtype: float64
```

You can then reset_index if you want it back to columns:

```
df_2.reset_index()
```